# Mobify carousel Infinite slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel, mobify-js

I am using [Mobify](https://github.com/mobify/scooch) carousel. I want to make it as Infite slider. 
To do this I change JS code by

```
if (newIndex < 1) {
    newIndex = length;
} else if (newIndex > this._length) { 
    newIndex = 1;
}
```

But when I reached at last image then click on next it goes to first image by right to left. I want to make it Left to right for last image and right to left for first image. and it work as a Infinite loop

Comment: And it isnt?  I mean, what is length at the point in time you set the `newIndex` and is it going into the correct conditional?

Comment: length is depends upon number of image.

Comment: I think you are going to need to get me some more information.  I will create a quick example though to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved this for you, I will show you my test case... and then i will show you what i did to adjust it for you.

```
var len = 6;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  console.log("value:", Number(i%len));
}
```

this shows just a loop, iterating over something of size 6, and resetting it back to 0, a continual loop forward.  Similarly, in the other direction.

```
var len = 6;
for (var i = 100; i >= 0; i--){
  console.log("value:", Number(i%len));
}
```

So you can sort of get mod to work forward.  for reverse, -1 would not mod with len to loop back to the end, so you could say:

```
var len = this._length;
newIndex%=len;
if(newIndex < 0){
  newIndex = len;
}
```

if there is an issue with `len`, then it means there is an issue with `this._length` which you defined.  You need to make sure you understand that when there is an array of items, say: 6.... their indices are actually 0 through 5.

That could be a secondary issue as per your question.